# Streaming CustomView ARcore with Twilio video

Tags: android, video-streaming, twilio, surfaceview, arcore

I've a problem when i want to streaming a custom view with twilio video api along with ARcore, basically it stream a black screen.
I used ViewCapturer class from example to this link https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/tree/master/exampleCustomVideoCapturer from the official documentation, but doen't work with arcore, probably due to the presence of the surface view in the arFragment.

Thank you for your support.

activity_camera.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CameraARActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ux_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#c100a5a0"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCloseChat"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="Close chat button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Row of localVideo creation:

```
screenVideoTrack = LocalVideoTrack.create(CameraARActivity.this, true, new ViewCapturer(mArFragment.getArSceneView()));
```

and the ViewCapturer class

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;

import com.twilio.video.VideoCapturer;
import com.twilio.video.VideoDimensions;
import com.twilio.video.VideoFormat;
import com.twilio.video.VideoFrame;
import com.twilio.video.VideoPixelFormat;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

/**
 * ViewCapturer demonstrates how to implement a custom {@link VideoCapturer}. This class
 * captures the contents of a provided view and signals the {@link VideoCapturer.Listener} when
 * the frame is available.
 */
public class ViewCapturer implements VideoCapturer {
    private static final int VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS = 100;

    private final View view;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private VideoCapturer.Listener videoCapturerListener;
    private AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final Runnable viewCapturer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean dropFrame = view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() == 0;

            // Only capture the view if the dimensions have been established
            if (!dropFrame) {
                // Draw view into bitmap backed canvas
                int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(),
                        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getHeight(),
                        View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
                view.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
                view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

                Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas viewCanvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
                view.draw(viewCanvas);

                // Extract the frame from the bitmap
                int bytes = viewBitmap.getByteCount();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
                viewBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
                byte[] array = buffer.array();
                final long captureTimeNs =
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

                // Create video frame
                VideoDimensions dimensions = new VideoDimensions(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
                VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(array,
                        dimensions, VideoFrame.RotationAngle.ROTATION_0, captureTimeNs);

                // Notify the listener
                if (started.get()) {
                    videoCapturerListener.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
                }
            }

            // Schedule the next capture
            if (started.get()) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
            }
        }
    };

    public ViewCapturer(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the list of supported formats for this view capturer. Currently, only supports
     * capturing to RGBA_8888 bitmaps.
     *
     * @return list of supported formats.
     */
    @Override
    public List<VideoFormat> getSupportedFormats() {
        List<VideoFormat> videoFormats = new ArrayList<>();
        VideoDimensions videoDimensions = new VideoDimensions(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        VideoFormat videoFormat = new VideoFormat(videoDimensions, 30, VideoPixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

        videoFormats.add(videoFormat);

        return videoFormats;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true because we are capturing screen content.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isScreencast() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * This will be invoked when it is time to start capturing frames.
     *
     * @param videoFormat the video format of the frames to be captured.
     * @param listener capturer listener.
     */
    @Override
    public void startCapture(VideoFormat videoFormat, Listener listener) {
        // Store the capturer listener
        this.videoCapturerListener = listener;
        this.started.set(true);

        // Notify capturer API that the capturer has started
        boolean capturerStarted = handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer,
                VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
        this.videoCapturerListener.onCapturerStarted(capturerStarted);
    }

    /**
     * Stop capturing frames. Note that the SDK cannot receive frames once this has been invoked.
     */
    @Override
    public void stopCapture() {
        this.started.set(false);
        handler.removeCallbacks(viewCapturer);
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
package com.bitdrome.dionigi.eragle.utils;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.PixelCopy;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

import com.twilio.video.VideoCapturer;
import com.twilio.video.VideoDimensions;
import com.twilio.video.VideoFormat;
import com.twilio.video.VideoFrame;
import com.twilio.video.VideoPixelFormat;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

/**
 * ViewCapturer demonstrates how to implement a custom {@link 
 VideoCapturer}. This class
 * captures the contents of a provided view and signals the {@link 
 VideoCapturer.Listener} when
 * the frame is available.
 */
public class ViewCapturer implements VideoCapturer, 
    PixelCopy.OnPixelCopyFinishedListener {
    private static int VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS = 10;

private final View view;
private Bitmap viewBitmap;
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private Handler handlerPixelCopy = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private VideoCapturer.Listener videoCapturerListener;
private AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public ViewCapturer(View view) {
    this(view, 24);
}

public ViewCapturer(View view, int framePerSecond) {
    if (framePerSecond <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("framePersecond must be greater than 0");
    this.view = view;
    float tmp = (1f / framePerSecond) * 1000;
    VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS = Math.round(tmp);
}

private final Runnable viewCapturer = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean dropFrame = view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() == 0;

        // Only capture the view if the dimensions have been established
        if (!dropFrame) {
            // Draw view into bitmap backed canvas
            int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(),
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getHeight(),
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            view.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
            view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

            viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            try {
                PixelCopy.request((SurfaceView) view, viewBitmap, ViewCapturer.this, handlerPixelCopy);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Returns the list of supported formats for this view capturer. Currently, only supports
 * capturing to RGBA_8888 bitmaps.
 *
 * @return list of supported formats.
 */
@Override
public List<VideoFormat> getSupportedFormats() {
    List<VideoFormat> videoFormats = new ArrayList<>();
    VideoDimensions videoDimensions = new VideoDimensions(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    VideoFormat videoFormat = new VideoFormat(videoDimensions, 30, VideoPixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    videoFormats.add(videoFormat);

    return videoFormats;
}

/**
 * Returns true because we are capturing screen content.
 */
@Override
public boolean isScreencast() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * This will be invoked when it is time to start capturing frames.
 *
 * @param videoFormat the video format of the frames to be captured.
 * @param listener    capturer listener.
 */
@Override
public void startCapture(VideoFormat videoFormat, Listener listener) {
    // Store the capturer listener
    this.videoCapturerListener = listener;
    this.started.set(true);

    // Notify capturer API that the capturer has started
    boolean capturerStarted = handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer,
            VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
    this.videoCapturerListener.onCapturerStarted(capturerStarted);
}

/**
 * Stop capturing frames. Note that the SDK cannot receive frames once this has been invoked.
 */
@Override
public void stopCapture() {
    this.started.set(false);
    handler.removeCallbacks(viewCapturer);
}

@Override
public void onPixelCopyFinished(int i) {

    // Extract the frame from the bitmap
    int bytes = viewBitmap.getByteCount();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
    viewBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    byte[] array = buffer.array();
    final long captureTimeNs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

    // Create video frame
    VideoDimensions dimensions = new VideoDimensions(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(array,
            dimensions, VideoFrame.RotationAngle.ROTATION_0, captureTimeNs);

    // Notify the listener
    if (started.get()) {
        videoCapturerListener.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
    }
    if (started.get()) {
        handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer, VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I found a solution, instead of use a Canvas i used PixelCopy class to copy the surfaceView in Bitmap, the rest is the same. I hope will helpful for someone.

Comment: Can you please post the code for your solution.

Comment: Hi @atalpha, sorry for the late answer.  I've answered in my post under solution section. Regards.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your solution. I had figured that out after a while. Thank you again for taking the time to post your solution.

Comment: @atalpha you're welcome.

Comment: Hi skytron I have same issue while trying to integrate Twilio and ArCore, could you please provide some more info I tryied what you have done but I didnt Succeed

Comment: Hi @PeppeS, what kind of error or mistake you have when you try to use the code under solution paragraph of my solution?

Comment: Hi skytron, I have some problem in adding a simple element(a sphere) in the Augemted reality of who replies to the videocall. I succeded in sending a string using DataTrack but it seems hard

Comment: @skytron87 I have tried your solution but it still shows me a black screen at the receiver end, could you please guide me, it's not giving any error

Comment: Hi @PareshRajput. I need more info to help you.

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how to do this in a native WebRTC code? It has VideoCapturer but not all these function implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Modified above code to provide stream at closest VGA resolution per Twilio docs. And added capability to swap surfaces and use null.

```
package com.company.app

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.SystemClock
import android.view.PixelCopy
import android.view.SurfaceView
import com.twilio.video.*
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock
import kotlin.math.roundToLong

class SurfaceViewCapturer : VideoCapturer {
    private var surfaceView: SurfaceView? = null

    private lateinit var viewBitmap: Bitmap
    private lateinit var videoCapturerListener: VideoCapturer.Listener

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val handlerPixelCopy = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private var started: Boolean = false

    // Twilio selects closest supported VideoFormat to 640x480 at 30 frames per second.
    // https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/video/releases/1.0.0-beta17/docs/com/twilio/video/LocalVideoTrack.html

    private val framesPerSecond: Int = 30
    private val streamWidth: Int = VideoDimensions.VGA_VIDEO_WIDTH
    private val streamHeight: Int = VideoDimensions.VGA_VIDEO_HEIGHT

    private val viewCapturerFrameRateMs: Long =
        (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1).toFloat() / framesPerSecond.toFloat()).roundToLong()

    private val reentrantLock = ReentrantLock()

    fun changeSurfaceView(surfaceView: SurfaceView?) {
        reentrantLock.lock()
        this.surfaceView = surfaceView
        reentrantLock.unlock()
    }

    private val viewCapturer: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            reentrantLock.lock()

            val surfaceView = surfaceView

            if (started.not()) {
                reentrantLock.unlock()
                return
            }

            if (surfaceView == null ||
                surfaceView.width == 0 ||
                surfaceView.height == 0 ||
                surfaceView.holder.surface.isValid.not()
            ) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, viewCapturerFrameRateMs)
                reentrantLock.unlock()
                return
            }

            // calculate frame width with fixed stream height while maintaining aspect ratio
            val frameWidthFixedHeight: Int = (surfaceView.width * streamHeight) / surfaceView.height

            // calculate frame height with fixed stream width while maintaining aspect ratio
            val frameHeightFixedWidth: Int = (surfaceView.height * streamWidth) / surfaceView.width

            // choose ratio that has more pixels
            val (frameWidth, frameHeight) =
                if (frameWidthFixedHeight * streamHeight >= frameHeightFixedWidth * streamWidth) {
                    Pair(frameWidthFixedHeight, streamHeight)
                } else {
                    Pair(streamWidth, frameHeightFixedWidth)
                }

            viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameWidth, frameHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

            // mutex.unlock() happens in callback
            PixelCopy.request(
                surfaceView,
                viewBitmap,
                {
                    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(viewBitmap.byteCount)
                    viewBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer)

                    // Create video frame
                    val dimensions = VideoDimensions(frameWidth, frameHeight)

                    val videoFrame =
                        VideoFrame(
                            buffer.array(),
                            dimensions,
                            VideoFrame.RotationAngle.ROTATION_0,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
                        )

                    // Notify the listener
                    videoCapturerListener.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame)
                    handler.postDelayed(this, viewCapturerFrameRateMs)
                    reentrantLock.unlock()
                },
                handlerPixelCopy
            )
        }
    }

    override fun getSupportedFormats(): List<VideoFormat> =
        listOf(
            VideoFormat(
                VideoDimensions(streamWidth, streamHeight),
                framesPerSecond,
                VideoPixelFormat.RGBA_8888
            )
        )

    override fun isScreencast(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun startCapture(
        captureFormat: VideoFormat,
        capturerListener: VideoCapturer.Listener
    ) {
        reentrantLock.lock()
        // Store the capturer listener
        videoCapturerListener = capturerListener
        started = true

        // Notify capturer API that the capturer has started
        val capturerStarted = handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer, viewCapturerFrameRateMs)
        videoCapturerListener.onCapturerStarted(capturerStarted)
        reentrantLock.unlock()
    }

    /**
     * Stop capturing frames. Note that the SDK cannot receive frames once this has been invoked.
     */
    override fun stopCapture() {
        reentrantLock.lock()
        started = false
        handler.removeCallbacks(viewCapturer)
        reentrantLock.unlock()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who must do stream ARCore with Twilio Video

In your ARCore render class.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
     ....
     this.takeLastFrame();
}

private byte[] takeLastFrame() {
    int height = this.mFrameHeight;
    int width = this.mFrameWidth;

    Mat input = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(input.rows() * input.cols() * input.channels());

    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height,
            GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    input.put(0, 0, buffer.array());

    Core.rotate(input, input, Core.ROTATE_180);
    Core.flip(input, input, 1);

    return convertMatToBytes(input);
}

private byte[] convertMatToBytes(Mat image) {
    int bufferSize = image.channels() * image.cols() * image.rows();
    byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
    image.get(0, 0, b);
    return b;
}
```

In your custom capturer class

```
byte[] array = view.takeLastFrame();
if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
    final long captureTimeNs = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

    // Create video frame
    VideoDimensions dimensions = new VideoDimensions(view.getFrameWidth(), view.getFrameHeight());
    VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(array,
                        dimensions, VideoFrame.RotationAngle.ROTATION_0, captureTimeNs);

    // Notify the listener
    if (started.get()) {
        videoCapturerListener.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
    }
}
```