# ARcore with Twilio video calling

Tags: java, android, twilio, arcore

How can I use ArFragment with twilio video calling?
I have added ArFragment with twilio using room participant but I got black screen for receiver side.

I have tried below link solution:
[Streaming CustomView ARcore with Twilio video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439822/streaming-customview-arcore-with-twilio-video)

In My Activity:

localVideoTrack = LocalVideoTrack.create(this,
                    true,
                    new ViewCapturer(arFragment.getArSceneView()),
                    LOCAL_VIDEO_TRACK_NAME);
            if (localVideoTrack != null) {
                localVideoTrack.addRenderer(videoTextureView);
            }

ViewCapturer Class:

public class ViewCapturer implements VideoCapturer {
    private static final int VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS = 100;

```
private final View view;
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private VideoCapturer.Listener videoCapturerListener;
private AtomicBoolean started = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private final Runnable viewCapturer = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean dropFrame = view.getWidth() == 0 || view.getHeight() == 0;

        // Only capture the view if the dimensions have been established
        if (!dropFrame) {
            // Draw view into bitmap backed canvas
            int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(),
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getHeight(),
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            view.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
            view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

            Bitmap viewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas viewCanvas = new Canvas(viewBitmap);
            view.draw(viewCanvas);

            // Extract the frame from the bitmap
            int bytes = viewBitmap.getByteCount();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
            viewBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] array = buffer.array();
            final long captureTimeNs =
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            // Create video frame
            VideoDimensions dimensions = new VideoDimensions(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
            VideoFrame videoFrame = new VideoFrame(array,
                    dimensions, VideoFrame.RotationAngle.ROTATION_0, captureTimeNs);

            // Notify the listener
            if (started.get()) {
                videoCapturerListener.onFrameCaptured(videoFrame);
            }
        }

        // Schedule the next capture
        if (started.get()) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
        }
    }
};

public ViewCapturer(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

/**
 * Returns the list of supported formats for this view capturer. Currently, only supports
 * capturing to RGBA_8888 bitmaps.
 *
 * @return list of supported formats.
 */
@NonNull
@Override
public List<VideoFormat> getSupportedFormats() {
    List<VideoFormat> videoFormats = new ArrayList<>();
    VideoDimensions videoDimensions = new VideoDimensions(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    VideoFormat videoFormat = new VideoFormat(videoDimensions, 30, VideoPixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    videoFormats.add(videoFormat);

    return videoFormats;
}

/**
 * Returns true because we are capturing screen content.
 */
@Override
public boolean isScreencast() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * This will be invoked when it is time to start capturing frames.
 *
 * @param videoFormat the video format of the frames to be captured.
 * @param listener capturer listener.
 */
@Override
public void startCapture(VideoFormat videoFormat, Listener listener) {
    // Store the capturer listener
    this.videoCapturerListener = listener;
    this.started.set(true);

    // Notify capturer API that the capturer has started
    boolean capturerStarted = handler.postDelayed(viewCapturer,
            VIEW_CAPTURER_FRAMERATE_MS);
    this.videoCapturerListener.onCapturerStarted(capturerStarted);
}

/**
 * Stop capturing frames. Note that the SDK cannot receive frames once this has been invoked.
 */
@Override
public void stopCapture() {
    this.started.set(false);
    handler.removeCallbacks(viewCapturer);
}
```

}

I have added ArFragment with Twilio Video Calling using Room.
How can I share Ar Camera using video call?